# ROS Answers SE migration: Rviz colorbar

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a cloud of PointXYZI and I'm visualising them in Rviz. With the rainbow transform for intensities (you know, high values are "blue" and low values are "red"), is there a way to get a colorbar to know which colors match which values?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/182444/rviz-colorbar/) by [crpizarr](https://answers.ros.org/users/9346/crpizarr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2014-07-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is standard HSV color palette cropped at 83.33% (or 5/6) of max hue value. This is because if it weren't cropped, then the color for the lowest and highest values would be the same.

You can plot it in matlab:

```
figure(1);
colorbar;
axis off;
map = hsv(100);
colormap(map(1:83,:));
set(gca, 'CLim', [min_value, max_value]);
```

---

Originally posted by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) with karma: 1366 on 2015-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2